# How can I add banner to product page? (magento)

Tags: php, magento, web, content-management-system

I have my homepage redirected to a product page, but I still want my banners from the home page to show up.

Anyone have any clue how I can add banners to my product page ? Pretty new to Magento... Certainly not as easy as Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are handles in Magento who decide what block to show when specific controller is called.
Take a look at this file 
**/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml** and find following lines

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!-- Some more code -->
            </block>
        </reference>
        <!-- Some more code -->
    </catalog_product_view>
```

**catalog_product_view** is the handle you may want to use for displaying the banner on product page.

Pick that handle and write the block specific code.

If you want to use an extension to simplify your task [here is the one.](http://www.magebuzz.com/banner-slider.html)

Comment: thaks for the comment. where do i find the block specific code for my banner though ? also, tried to install that extension in the Magento Connect admin panel, but was unable due to errors (incorrect name, no date, invalid characters, etc). Am I installing in right place? I uploaded the package to Magento Connect Manager > file upload

Comment: For installing an extension, disable the cache first. 
Use the magento connect key to download the zip file of the extension from http://www.freegento.com/ Use direct download magento extension and just paste the key. 
Upload the extension files to root of Magento, check the file/folder permissions. 
Follow this simple video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvqY3zhjF-c

Comment: For the bannerslider block specific code is similar to this
<block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="1"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can call banner code on products page. Or if you want to go with simple technique, use iframe